# After moving root directory on webserver old directory path is still used sometimes

Tags: php, apache

I've just moved a directory for my website to another location under `/var/www`

From: 
`/var/www/site/beta`

To:
`/var/www/site`

When trying to load the page several of the files are still trying to load from:
`/var/www/site/beta`

This is on an AWS server so I'm not sure what should be done. Are these paths cached somewhere?

EDIT:
In several cases **dirname(__FILE__)** is still referring to the old location:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/class-file.php';
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like cashing to me. Have you tried resetting your browser's cache or use a browser where you haven't tested that site in before?

Comment: Yes, I've tried clearing cache etc and several different browsers.  It acts like the server has cached the old path somehow